# Getting a string from a line that follows a certain character

Tags: bash, packer

From a file I'm retrieving the last line using the following cmd;

```
tail -n 1 build.log
```

The output looks like this:

`1477101542,,ui,say,--> amazon-ebs: AMIs were created:\n\nus-east-1: ami-63237174\nus-west-1: ami-21236841\nus-west-2: ami-27872347`

I'm trying to fetch the string after `us-east-1:`, `us-west-1:` & `us-west-2` using the following grep commands:

```
echo | tail -n 1 build.log | egrep -m1 -oe 'us-east-1: ami-.{8}' |  egrep -m1 -oe 'ami-.{8}'
```

I run this cmd three times for each condition. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "I'm trying to fetch the string after ...". Please learn to include expected output from given sample input and avoid misunderstandings about what you are trying to achieve ;-). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order in which the regions appear is fixed, you can simply do:

```
$ echo | tail -n 1 build.log | egrep -o  'ami-.{8}'
ami-63237174
ami-21236841
ami-27872347
```

---

If you want to extract the *region names* and you have *GNU* `grep`, try:

```
$ echo | tail -n 1 build.log | grep -Po 'us-[^:]+(?=: ami-.{8})'
us-east-1
us-west-1
us-west-2
```

---

To get *both* region names and associated values:

```
$ echo | tail -n 1 build.log | egrep -o 'us-[^:]+: ami-.{8}'
us-east-1: ami-63237174
us-west-1: ami-21236841
us-west-2: ami-27872347
```

Comment: I would want to identify the regions as well

Comment: Please see my update and please clarify your exact requirements (_directly in your question_).

Comment: I wanted to identify which ami id im trying to retrieve